# Deleting UITableView sections combined with custom section headers UIViews = bug in Apple's code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-animation, nsindexset

I'm trying to delete a section from a UITableView using animation and custom table section header UIViews.

I use...

```
//Deletion from my model done here (not shown) and then perform the deleteSections...
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView 
  deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:index]
  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

This works fine when I provide the section titles using

```
tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
```

But when I provide my own custom header using

```
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

It deletes the desired section and shifts all the sections below it up. What I think is happening is it is asking for the new custom header just before it does the deletion animation. So it animates the removal of the desiredRow+1.

I end up with every section shifted up by one and a blank section at the bottom.

If I scroll to the bottom of the table then come back the sections are found properly again.

I don't think this is something I can fix. It seems like a problem in Apple's code handling section deletion with custom section headers. Usually it's a good idea to blame myself first :) . I'm using the same logic to find the model object for my custom section headers vs. the NSString section titles so I cannot see how it could be a problem with my code.

Anyone know how to fix this or should I rethink my use of sections?

Comment: I wish Apple would add it's own dequeue for sections like it does for stock header views. This is one of the annoying things about customising the headers in table views. Another annoyance is the requirement of at least one section.

Comment: What if you try it using an animation? I just implemented the same and apart from some not-fancy-looking animations with the section headers,  I don't have to problem you're describing. I am using a row animation, you may always want to try it to be able to narrow down where the problem occurs.

Comment: Hi JoostK, I have used an animation. I see I mistakenly posted the code with UITableViewRowAnimationNone because I was trying to see if turning off animations would solve it... It didn't. In your code are you using custom headers or are you just using the default section headers?

Answer (score 0):

I was solved this issue to call reloadSections:atIndexPath:
This is a one way.
Other ways :
Reload table (you may loose animation)
Using a fetch controller and some property in u header view. When u delete one object fetch controller can do reload sections for u.